# Fastify error handler returns wrong error if I call reply.code() before returning the error object

Tags: fastify

I have an async error handler that looks like this

```
export default async function processError(
  err: FastifyError,
  req: FastifyRequest,
  res: FastifyReply
): Promise<FastifyError | TErrorReply> {
  console.log({ err: err.stack });
  let processedError: TErrorReply = err;
  if (isDatabaseError(err))
    processedError = processDatabaseError(req, res, err);
  if (isSchemaValidationError(err))
    processedError = processSchemaValidationError(req, res, err);

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    processedError = {
      ...processedError,
      stack: err.stack || new Error().stack,
    };
  console.log({ processedError });
  res.code(Number(err?.code || err?.statusCode || 500));
  return processedError;
}
```

I then use it like this

```
  fastify.setErrorHandler(processError);
```

Inside `processSomethingError` functions I set a specific code and return a specific error, here is an example.

```
function processDatabaseError(
  req: FastifyRequest,
  res: FastifyReply,
  err: DatabaseError
): TErrorReply {
  const t = getFixedT('en', 'errors');
  switch (err.code) {
    case '23505': {
      const match = err.detail?.match(/\((.+?)\)/);
      if (match) {
        const key = match[1];
        res.code(409);
        return {
          fields: { [key]: 'duplicated' },
        };
      }
    }
  }
  res.code(400);
  return {
    message: t<string, TTranslationKeys['errors']>('fallback'),
  };
}
```

My problem is that if I have
`res.code(Number(err?.code || err?.statusCode || 500));`
inside `processError`, just before returning the `processedError`, it ignores the `processedError` and instead sends the original error, which is represented by the `err` argument inside `processError` function.
If I remove the `res.code..` - everything works fine and the actual `processedError` is returned.

Why is it working like this?
I just want to set the code or the error I want to return, so in headers it shows the right status code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `err?.code` is a string, so it would throw an error inside `res.code` function since it wants a number.